# Generate dynamic form input fields and collect field data in an array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to generate form input fields dynamically by clicking 'add sale' button on the form. which is accomplished

Also on change selected drop down, it get the price from the database and use the quantity to calculate the amount of that product.

if I click on 'add sale' button for another form generate the changes affect the previous one.

how to calculate the amount for each form independently and collect the data in it using angularJS?

this is controller

```
appcat.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location)
{
    //var quan = $scope.quantity;
    $http.get('/api/pproduct').success(function (data)
    {
        $scope.pcategoryA = data;
    });

    // this controll the addition and removal
    $scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }];

    //any time changes occurr it calculate the Amount 
    $scope.changedValue = function (item,quan)
    {


        if (item != null && quan !=null)
        {

            $http.get('/api/product/'+ item).success(function (data) // this is the price for that product from the Database
            {
                //this sets amount field
                $scope.amount = parseFloat(data.price * quan);

            });

        }
    }

    // this generate a form
    $scope.addNewChoice = function ()
    {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ 'id': 'choice' + newItemNo });
    };

    // this remove the form
    $scope.removeChoice = function () {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        if ($scope.choices.length > 1) {
            $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
        }
    };


}]);
```

this is the html

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" padding-left:10em">
                    <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">
                            Invoice No. : 
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" />
                    </div>
                    <br /><hr />
                    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                        <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Quantity :
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" ng-model="quantity" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label"> Product : </label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="selected_id" ng-model="selected_id" ng-options="c.Value as c.Text for c in pcategoryA"
                                            ng-change="changedValue(selected_id,quantity)">

                                        <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Amount :
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" ng-model="amount"  ng-readonly="true" />       
                            </div>

                            <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
                            <br />
                            <hr />

                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="col-sm-offset-10 addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
                            Add Sale
                        </button>
                    </div>


                </form>
```

thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put 'amount' in choices array.

```
$scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1', amount: 0}];
```

Then in controller:

```
$scope.changedValue = function (choise,item,quan)

choise.amount = parseFloat(data.price * quan);
```

And in tempalte:

```
ng-change="changedValue(choise,selected_id,quantity)">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" ng-model="choise.amount"  ng-readonly="true" />
```

Comment: Actually I get all the value right and the calculation also is fine but the issue is; the  Generated form is not distinct from the previous one
how can I distinguish them such that the amount will be calculated for each form generated

Comment: Exactly as I said, you should keep calculated amount of each form in $scope.choices array together with form id.